# `babel-preset-react` not transforming jsx with gulp

Tags: jsx, babeljs, gulp-babel

No matter what I try, something like `<div/>` is not being transformed to `React.createClass` and the browser just obviously chokes on the first `<` in my code.

I'm using gulp like:

```
  return gulp.src(files)
     .pipe(babel({
        presets: [ "react", "es2015" ],
        plugins: [ "transform-react-jsx" ]          
      }))
     .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

I've tried with and without `transform-react-jsx` because I believe the `react` preset should transform jsx as well?

This is my `.babelrc`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference, and I read somewhere that in some cases you need to delete it to work. Tried it, didn't help.

```
{
    "presets": [ "react", "es2015" ],
    "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

in my package.json:

```
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.8.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "~6.5.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"gulp-babel": "~6.1.2",
...
```

I've tried just about anything, but it just **does not transform my code**

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, there was a `gulp-changed` step in between that broke it. Removing that fixed it for me.

You'd think it "is able to detect whether files in the stream changed" like the docs say, but I guess this is not the case.